# Installing Jekyll to a live HTML website

Tags: html, web, content-management-system, jekyll

I am trying to deploy Jekyll, I can do so successfully when deploying it as a new website. I want to deploy it to a subfolder named Blog '/mysite/Blog'. I understand that localhost:4000 initializes jekyll to deploy, but how does this work when i want to link to it from the main site '/mysite/blog/'. This results in just the site directory showing as shown:

[image]

I am having trouble finding documentation targeting this specific problem. I dont want to deploy this to the live site unless im 100% sure

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that localhost:4000 initializes jekyll to deploy

No, it doesn't.

That's the default URL of the development server… which you use for development, not deployment.

See [the basic usage instructions](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/usage/):

> ```
> $ jekyll build
> # => The current folder will be generated into ./_site
> ```

You have static files. Copy them to your live server as you would any other static files.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to set `baseurl` in `_config.yml` :

```
baseurl: /blog
```

Verify that resources are called with `{{ site.baseurl }}{{ page.url }}` or `{{ site.baseurl }}/path/to/asset.js/css/jpg`.

During development (`jekyll serve`) you will reach your site at `localhost:4000/blog/` and you can deploy this code in you `site/blog` folder.